# Does memory ordering of a locked instruction has a corresponding assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, atomic, memory-barriers, memory-model

I know that `Lock` prefix in assembly creates a locked instruction that somehow similar to an atomic operation. But atomic operations in higher level languages normally have a memory ordering too (such as relaxed, released, and acquire memory ordering).

I wonder if these memory ordering will be translated into an assembly instruction or prefix too. Any idea?

**Update:** My question is about x86.

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?  This sounds a lot like x86 where the `lock` prefix iirc implies sequentially consistent ordering.

Comment: @fuz yes, I was asking for x86. but what happens if someone compiles its code with another memory ordering?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447226/atomicity-on-x86 might be helpful.  The short, somewhat oversimplified description of memory ordering in x86 machine code is "ordinary loads are acquire, ordinary stores are release, the `lock` prefix provides sequential consistency".  So for example C++'s `tmp = a.load(std::memory_order_acquire);` will compile into a simple `mov eax, [a]`.

Comment: @Afshin In this case the memory ordering will be stricter than required by the program which is not generally a problem.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Why does memory\_order\_relaxed use atomic (lock-prefixed) instructions on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24234769) - all atomic RMW operations on x86 are full barriers, so only compile-time ordering is possible even if you only write `fetch_add(mo_relaxed)` in your C++ source.  Ah, found a previous answer of mine where I explained how C++ orders correspond to x86 asm, [Are memory orderings: consume, acq\_rel and seq\_cst ever needed on Intel x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61719680) works as a dup I think.  (And has links to more details for lots of stuff)