# Memory ordering for a spin-lock "call once" implementation

Tags: c, gcc, x86, atomic, memory-barriers

Suppose I wanted to implement a mechanism for calling a piece of code exactly once (e.g. for initialization purposes), even when multiple threads hit the call site repeatedly. Basically, I'm trying to implement something like `pthread_once`, but with GCC atomics and spin-locking. I have a candidate implementation below, but I'd like to know if

a) it could be faster in the common case (i.e. already initialized), and,

b) is the selected memory ordering strong enough / too strong?

Architectures of interest are x86_64 (primarily) and aarch64.

The intended use API is something like this

```
void gets_called_many_times_from_many_threads(void)
{  
    static int my_once_flag = 0;
     
    if (once_enter(&my_once_flag)) {
        // do one-time initialization here
        once_commit(&my_once_flag);
    }

    // do other things that assume the initialization has taken place
}
```

And here is the implementation:

```
int once_enter(int *b)
{
    int zero = 0;
    int got_lock = __atomic_compare_exchange_n(b, &zero, 1, 0, __ATOMIC_RELAXED, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    if (got_lock) return 1;

    while (2 != __atomic_load_n(b, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)) {
        // on x86, insert a pause instruction here
    };
    return 0;
}

void once_commit(int *b)
{
    (void) __atomic_store_n(b, 2, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}
```

I think that the RELAXED ordering on the compare exchange is okay, because we don't skip the atomic load in the while condition even if the compare-exchange gives us 2 (in the "zero" variable), so the ACQUIRE on that load synchronizes with the RELEASE in `once_commit` (I think), but maybe on a successful compare-exchange we need to use RELEASE? I'm unclear here.

Also, I [just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814444/memory-order-for-a-ticket-taking-spin-lock-mutex) that `lock cmpxchg` is a full memory barrier on x86, and since we are hitting the `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` in the common case (initialization has already been done), that barrier it is occurring on every function call. Is there an easy way to avoid this?

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments and accepted answer, I've come up with the following modified implementation. If anybody spots a bug please let me know, but I believe it's correct. Basically, the change amounts to implementing double-check locking. I also switched to using SEQ_CST because:

- I mainly care that the common (already initialized) case is fast.
- I observed that GCC doesn't emit a memory fence instruction on x86 for the first read (and it does do so on ARM even with ACQUIRE).

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
#define PAUSE()  __asm __volatile("pause")
#else
#define PAUSE()
#endif

int once_enter(int *b)
{
    if(2 == __atomic_load_n(b, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)) return 0;

    int zero = 0;
    int got_lock = __atomic_compare_exchange_n(b, &zero, 1, 0, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    if (got_lock) return 1;

    while (2 != __atomic_load_n(b, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)) {
        PAUSE();
    };
    return 0;
}

void once_commit(int *b)
{
    (void) __atomic_store_n(b, 2, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}
```

Comment: Generally an atomic RMW is still the most efficient way to get mutual exclusion, even though it costs a full memory barrier on x86.  Alternatives include Dekker's algorithm, but that's usually even slower and actually requires a full memory barrier (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Oh, but yeah in this case, like a guard variable for a static initializer, you only need mutual exclusion after finding out that the call_once hasn't happened yet.  The fast-path should be a read-only check.  My previous comment was mostly just replying to the sentence about lock cmpxchg being a full barrier; you definitely want a read-only check even on ISAs that can do relaxed or acquire RMWs in asm, unless they bail out before actually invalidating the cache line on other cores.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using GCC builtin atomics instead of the equally capable, and much more portable, C11 atomics from `<stdatomic.h>`?

Comment: For AArch64, you might want to switch to a different primitive than `compare_exchange`.  ARMv8.1 has a suite of single-instruction atomic read-modify-write operations, including set/clear/toggle bits, and integer add, min and max.  But not compare-exchange, so that has to fall back to a `ldxr/stxr` loop as on ARMv8.0, whose forward progress is less certain.

Comment: One possible alternative would be to have a pair of boolean flags, one to indicate whether initialization has started, and the other to indicate whether it has finished.  So then if the `finished` flag is unset, you atomically test-and-set the `started` flag, and continue with the initialization if you see that it was previously false; otherwise you spin until `finished` becomes true.  Atomic test-and-set is a single instruction on ARMv8.1 (`LDSETB` and its acquire/release variants).  For x86 and ARMv8.0, test-and-set is about the same as compare-exchange, performance-wise.

Comment: Not that it makes too much difference here, since once you are using a double-checked lock, the atomic read-modify-write is out of the fast path anyway.  But maybe worth noting in general.

Comment: You do want `acquire` not `seq_cst` for the fast-path load.  That's cheaper on AArch64 (`ldapr` instead of `ldar`) and PowerPC, among others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a, What you need is a [double-checked lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

Basically, instead of entering the lock every time, you do an acquiring-load to see if the initialisation has been done yet, and only invoke `once_enter` if it has not.

```
void gets_called_many_times_from_many_threads(void)
{  
    static int my_once_flag = 0;

    if (__atomic_load_n(&my_once_flag, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE) != 2) {
        if (once_enter(&my_once_flag)) {
            // do one-time initialization here
            once_commit(&my_once_flag);
        }
    }

    // do other things that assume the initialization has taken place
}
```

b, I believe this is enough, your initialisation happens before the releasing store of 2 to `my_once_flag`, and every other thread has to observe the value of 2 with an acquiring load from the same variable.